# Orchard 1.10.2 - Issue with styles for workflow activities

Tags: css, workflow, orchardcms

I created a custom module that defines a new activity to use inside workflows, but this created an error in the editing page of the workflow, because the module Orchard.Workflows is searching for a css with the same name of the activity in its `Styles` folder.

Is there any way to tell Orchard to search elsewhere for that css or to not search it at all? The number of errors will grow with every new activity defined and it doesn't seem like a good behavior to me.

Comment: Where does Orchard attempt to load the styles?

Comment: They are dynamically defined in the ResourceManifest of Orchard.Workflows.
The View that tries to load them is under the folder Views/Admin/Edit.

Comment: I think you can override it by defining a different style with the same name in your own ResourceManifest.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - the logic that renders the `<LINK>` element is hard-coded, and it is "by design" that it will try and load a CSS file whose URL is determined based on a convention. This will change with [Orchard Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/21/orchard-core-beta-annoucement/) (the next major version of Orchard), but for Orchard 1 your best bet is to simply provide a CSS file if you care about reducing the 404s.